# numba error when compiling python script to exe

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I have a python script that I have compiled into an exe. The script runs perfect in vscode but compiling to exe breaks it. The block of code that seems to be causing the error is:

```
@njit()
def mahalanobis_distance(xj, ai,sigma):
inverse = np.linalg.inv(sigma + (0.001 * np.identity(3)))
correction = np.log(np.linalg.det(inverse))
return np.float64(((xj - ai) @ inverse @ (xj-ai).T) - correction)
```

When I run the compiled exe I get the following error:

```
2023-05-09 15:51:18,781:INFO:root:FCM Mahalanobis algorithm:
2023-05-09 15:51:19,019:INFO:root:Iteration: 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "FCM_Package.py", line 44, in main
File "FCM_Package.py", line 684, in FCM_Mahalanobis
File "numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 468, in _compile_for_args
File "numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 409, in error_rewrite
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
No implementation of function Function(<function inv at 0x000001AC42BA9240>) found for signature:

>>> inv(array(float64, 2d, C))

There are 2 candidate implementations:
- Of which 2 did not match due to:
Overload in function 'inv_impl': File: numba\np\linalg.pyc: Line 0.
With argument(s): '(array(float64, 2d, C))':
Rejected as the implementation raised a specific error:
ImportError: scipy 0.16+ is required for linear algebra
raised from numba\np\linalg.py:65

...
```

Given this I tried a few things. I did a fresh install of Python making sure all the correct packages and versions are in the environment. Not sure why I still get "ImportError: scipy 0.16+ is required for linear algebra" after doing this.

I tried removing the inv function and using pinv or just not having the inverse calculated. That results in a similar error to the above except the det() function is causing the error. I'm not super experienced in numba so I'm not sure why it can't use the inv function with the given arguments. Does anyone have any ideas for what could be causing this and potential solutions?

Comment: Yep, cx_Freeze or pyinstaller guess what includes are required for a particular set of code, but sometimes they guess wrong. You can explicitly force includes in both. https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup_script.html